# Linq Order by List<int> of IDs given

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to sort a linq query so that the results are returned in the order of the IDs found in the List[int]. Here is my current code that returns them just fine, but not sorted.

```
IEnumerable<NPost> nposts;

List<int> npostIDs = (from tc in db.TopComs
                      where tc.Type == "Comments"
                      select tc.NPostID).ToList();

            nposts = from np in repository.NPosts
                     where npostIDs.Contains(np.NPostID)
                     select np;
```

How can I have it so that nposts returns the results in the order in which npostIDs exists in the List[int]?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<NPost> nposts = from np in repository.NPosts
                            let index = npostIDs.IndexOf(np.NPostID) 
                            where index >= 0
                            orderby index ascending
                            select np;
```

### Update

Based on your error, I've got another suggestion.  I'm not 100% sure if it will work or not in EF, but give it a try and let me know.  There's one other idea I have that I know would work but it's not going to perform as well.

```
IEnumerable<NPost> nposts = from npostID in npostIDs.AsQueryable()
                            join np in repository.NPosts
                            on npostID equals np.NPostID
                            select np;
```

This will maintain the order of the `npostIDs` without an `orderby` clause.  If the `ObjectContext` is the same (and maybe if it's not), you should actually be able to do it in a single query.  However, it's not clear if you are caching the `npostIDs` list or not, so this might not be an option.  Anyway, here:

```
IEnumerable<NPost> nposts = from tc in db.TopComs
                            where tc.Type == "Comments"
                            join np in repository.NPosts
                            on tc.NPostID equals np.NPostID
                            select np;
```

Comment: I personally like a method called `IndefOx` :)

Comment: @smartcaveman I tried running this and it gave me this exception:
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Thoughts?

Comment: @AdamFrick, Is the relationship between NPosts and npostIDs in the list 1-1 or 1-many? I'm thinking a join should work with EF

Comment: @smartcaveman the relationship is as such. TopComs is a table that I use to store data that is specific to calculating lists like most viewed post, etc. It contains TopComsID (key), Type (Views, Comments,etc.), NPostID (relates to NPost Table). It is technically a 1-many since each type could have a npostid that are shared, but since I will only ever work with one type at a time, you could call it a 1-1 relationship. Make sense?

Comment: @smartcaveman I was able to get it working using the join as you suggested. Thank!

Comment: @AdamFrick, Ah, well good.  I posted the code anyway.  Checkout the second version of it to see if it's helpful for your use case.

Comment: @smartcaveman The third set of code you posted is nearly identical to what I ended up using.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is correct, I just wanted to provide the method version of this answer:

```
IEnumerable<NPost> nposts = repository.NPosts
                            .Where(np => npostIDs.IndexOf(np.NPostID) >= 0)
                            .OrderBy(np => npostIDs.IndexOf(np.NPostID));
```